# Can't display javascript object properties in inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object, innerhtml

I'm trying to better understand javascript objects and how to actually put some data back into div. I created simple form in order to: 1.) retrieve data to HTML, 2.) made them into variables, 3.)display those variables in another div(to see if previous step worked fine) 4.) use variables to construct object 5.) display object's properties in div (again to see if previous step worked fine). No matter what do i do, i cannot display object's variables in HTML.

```js
function processFormData() {
 
 var fname = document.getElementById('input-name');
 var sname = document.getElementById('input-surname');
 
 var fnameTest = "Name: " + fname.value; 
 var snameTest = "Surname: " + sname.value;
 
 
 document.getElementById('fname-display').innerHTML=fnameTest;
 document.getElementById('sname-display').innerHTML=snameTest;

 People();

}

function People(fname,sname) {
 this.fn = fname;
 this.sn = sname;
 
}

var people = new People(
    fname,
    sname,
);

//function showPeople() {
// alert(people.fn);
//  alert(people.sn);
//};

function processObjData() {
 
 var objFname = "Name: " + people.sn; 
 var objSname = "Surname: " + people.sn;
 
 showPeople();

}

function showPeople() {
 document.getElementById('fname-display-obj').innerHTML=objFname;
 document.getElementById('sname-display-obj').innerHTML=objSname;
};

showPeople();
```

```html
<form action="#">
<div class="col">
<input type="text" name="fname" id="input-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="sname" id="input-surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="processFormData(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="col visual">
 <div id="fname-display"></div>
 <div id="sname-display"></div>
</div>
<div class="col visual">
 <div id="fname-display-obj"></div>
 <div id="sname-display-obj"></div>
</div>
```

If i run it in console, but with part alert making version of

```
showPeople()
```

(here disabled) and without whole rest, alerts display normally. 
I tried also bracket notation or putting

```
.value
```

after properties but nothing worked.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check your development tools output - hit "F12" in your browser and reload the page.

Comment: What is `var people = new People(
    fname,
    sname,
);` supposed to do? You haven't set the variables `fname` and `sname`. That should probably be inside `processFormData`.

Comment: It looks like you don't understand variable scope. You set the variables `objFname` and `objSname` inside the `processObjData()` function, but try to use them in `showPeople()`.

Comment: `People();` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: You really need to go back to the books and learn the basics of the language.

Comment: it suppose construct new Object

Comment: @Barmar The HTML5 standard [7.3.3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)  supports `window`  named properties "...for all HTML elements that have a non-empty id content attribute...",  making `fname` and `sname` valid  property references (after the document is ready). However, _7.3.3 does start with a note saying to use  `document.getElemenetById` or `document.querySelector` instead._

Comment: @Traktor53 Read more carefully. The only named elements that become `window` properties are  `embed`, `form`, `frameset`, `img`, and `object`, not `input`. For all element types, the `id` attribute becomes the `window` property.